# Convert code into .dll , open & modify exist .dll file

Tags: asp.net, .net, dll

What is the basic purpose to convert code into .dll  Is it must,and can we open & modify exist .dll file ,how?

Is Dll file has version ? If we Code .dll in Visual Studio 2005 is it support to every other version in VS2008 ,2010,2012 & 2013 and also for every versions of .net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A DLL file is just a .exe without a `static void Main(string[] args)` function. It follows all the rules a exe does for opening a project across versions of visual studio, and has the same rules for compatibility across .NET versions as a normal exe. It just lets you break apart your code in to smaller chunks so if you want to update a subcomponent of your code or use a subcomponent written by someone else you don't need to include the code inside the project of your main exe.

A dll can't really be "opened" like a exe because the act of opening a exe is it causes the `static void Main(string[] args)` function to be run (which a dll does not have). You can't "edit" a compiled dll very much either, it would just like if you where wanting to "edit" a exe.